# access variable from index.ts to a component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native, electron

I am new to electron and making one desktop application. In the index.ts file i am creating a window using this code.

```
  function createWindow(){

  win = new BrowserWindow();
  win.loadURL(`file://${__dirname}/index_beta.html`);
  win.setFullScreen(true);
  win.setMenu(null);
  return win;

  }
```

I have one more component where i have to resize this window object and I am struggling a lot in passing the BrowserWindow handle to the component. Is there any way using react that i can resize the window with the 'win' handle in the other component

Answer (score 0):

[Handle Browser Window Resize in React](https://www.hawatel.com/blog/handle-window-resize-in-react/)